# Model's Bean's map attribute is lost after validation?

Tags: spring-mvc

@RequestMapping(value = "/Summary/addPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)

```
public String getEmployeeAddPage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

    logger.info("INSIDE getEmployeeAddPage");

    EmployeeForm empForm = empService.getEmployeeAddPageFormData();

    model.addAttribute("empForm", empForm);
    model.addAttribute("actionUrl", request.getRequestURL());

    return "/Employee/AddEmployee";

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/Summary/addPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String employeeFormSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @RequestParam("action") String action, @Valid @ModelAttribute("empForm") EmployeeForm empForm,
        BindingResult result) {

    try {

        empFormValidator.validate(empForm, result);

        model.addAttribute("empForm", empForm);
        model.addAttribute("actionUrl", request.getRequestURL());

        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            logger.info("has Errors");
            return "/Employee/AddEmployee";
        } else {
            String actionStatus = empService.saveEmployeeDetails(empForm);
            empForm.setActionStatus(actionStatus);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
        empForm.setActionStatus("error");
    }

    return "/Employee/AddEmployee";
}
```

When I submit the page the empForm attribute is submitted to second method after which if validation fails it returns to same page. But this time the map field inside the empForm used for select option on JSP is lost.
What should I do so that map fields inside the empForm is retained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
@SessionAttributes(value = {"empForm"}, types = {EmployeeForm.class})
```

at the class level to resolve the issue.